# Not normally distributed raw data are compatible with a multiple linear regression?

Tags: multiple-regression

I have to analyse the predictive value of some neuropsychological data (ex time taken to complete a test, anxiety scores..) with a multiple linear regression model.If the raw data don't follow a normal distribution what I have to do? My prof told me that if there is a really big asimmetry I can transform them in z-scores...it is correct?
Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Many (*many*) answers and comments on site address this already. There's no assumption about the distribution of IVs whatever, and there's no assumption about the raw (i.e. marginal) DV either. *If* you use a test that assumes normality, there's an assumption about the conditional distribution of the DV (which people tend to assess by looking at residuals).

Answer (score 2):

A standard assumption in linear regression is that the *residuals* will be normal.$^{\dagger}$ We do not, however, care about the distribution of the response variable (e.g. `hist(y)`), and we definitely do not care about the distribution of the predictor variables.

The assumption of normal residuals is not essential to estimating the parameters, note. In particular, the legendary Gauss-Markov theorem that gives conditions where the estimated parameters have a nice statistical property called *unbiasedness* does not assume normal residuals. The normal residuals help with doing hypothesis testing and confidence intervals on the parameters, which may be of interest to you.

I think your professor's comment has to do with accounting for when variables are on wildly different scales, such as having one variable range from $0$ to $0.001$ and another range from $0$ to $987,654,321$. Transforming to a z-score could help with some issues related to doing calculations on a computer. However, that has nothing to do with the distribution of data being normal or not.

$^{\dagger}$Technically speaking, the assumption is about the error term, which we do not observe but estimate by the residuals. See Glen’s comments.

Comment: The assumption is actually about the errors; the residuals are simply an estimate of those; the residuals are neither independent nor identically distributed (while the errors are presumed to be both).

Answer (score -1):

I would expect time taken and anxiety scores to be normally distributed. Check for outliers using Cooks Distance and z-scores that are greater than some large size (e.g. greater than 4.0). You might choose to do a transformation, in which case I'd suggest Box-Cox transformation.

Comment: As my post indicates, it is not the distribution of data but the distribution of residuals (estimating the error term) that concerns us in regression.

Comment: Time taken will not be normally distributed -- it's necessarily positive. Times are typically right skew. Anxiety scores are presumably discrete and so not actually normal either. This may not matter much.